# Python > Mechanize > OpenSSL

Tags: python, ssl, mechanize

Hey I am trying to make a request using the mechanize library. Here is my code.

```
browser = mechanize.Browser()
##Navigate to https address
browser.open(landing_page)
##Query for zipcode
browser.select_form(form_name)
browser.form['cfsearchtextboxmain'] = zipcode
##Click Button
browser.submit()
```

When I try and open the page with mechanize I get this error.

> File "/Users/charleslane/Desktop/taxsale/virt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 1160, in do_open
>       raise URLError(err)
>
> URLError: urlopen error [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)>

How to I overcome this ssl issue with mechanize?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the library security packages:

```
pip install requests[security]
```

I have this versión

```
>>> import ssl
>>> print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
```